# why Read procedure insert New Line if user press the Enter keyboard?

Tags: console-application, pascal, freepascal

i'm trying to work with "Read" procedure instead of "ReadLn" inside Free Pascal IDE but when i press enter after typing the value for it i get a new line like "readln" does....

```pascal
program test;
uses
  crt;
var
  AName: string[20];

function Complete_Rectangle(ALength_NewValue, ALength_Rectangle, ALength_Pref: byte): string;
const
  Stars : string = '**';
var
  Space_Str: string;
  I,
  Space_Needed : byte;
begin
  Space_Needed := ALength_Rectangle - ALength_Pref; (* Calculate Needed Space.... *)
  Space_Str  := '';

  for I:=1 to Space_Needed -(ALength_NewValue + 2) do  (* 2 represent the length of Stars Constant *)
  begin
    Space_Str := Space_Str + ' ';
  end;

  Complete_Rectangle := Space_Str + Stars;
end;

begin
  clrscr;
  writeln('**********************************************************************');
  writeln('**                                                                  **');
    write('**  [*] add your Name here: '); read(AName); writeln(Complete_Rectangle(length(AName), 70, 28));
    (* 70 represent the length of rectangle spaces and 28 represent the length of this prefix text "**  [*] add your Name here: " *)
  writeln('**                                                                  **');
  writeln('**********************************************************************');
  readkey;
end.
```

is it possible to create my own custom Read to fix the problem above ?
i have this code here but it seems doesn't work properly ...:

```pascal
procedure Lire(AVariant: Variant);
var
  I: byte;
  AKey: Char;
  AReadStr: String;
begin
  I := 1;
  AReadStr := '';
  AKey := char('');

  repeat
    AKey := ReadKey;
    if not (AKey = #13) then
    begin
      AReadStr[I] := AKey;
      write(AKey);
      inc(I);
    end;
  Until AKey = #13;
  case varType(AVariant) of
    varString: begin AVariant := AReadStr; end;
    varInteger: begin AVariant := StrToInt(AReadStr); end;
    varByte: begin AVariant := StrToInt(AReadStr); end;
    varBoolean: begin AVariant := StrToBool(AReadStr); end;
    (* ..... and so on *)
  end;


end;
```

Comment: Good idea Mr: Tom Brunberg  i will try that now and i will reply ASAP. thanks.

Comment: You are right but from bad to the worst ... (yes it doesn't add a new line but On the other hand it's clear back the uses line and keep the new write or writeln after ....

Comment: program test;

var
  AName: string[20];


begin
  write('**  [*] add your Name here: '); read(AName); writeln('               **');

  readln;
end.  if i remove the unit crt ? yes doesn't return (doesn't add new line) as i said above but it clearback the usses line even the value of read and keep just the the next write or writeln after ...

Comment: I did some own investigation here as well, tracing into the source. The string returned by `read()` does not have `CRLF` characters. But while user is typing, the characters are sent to the screen, including the `CRLF` and that is what messes up your display. I'm afraid you can only use the answer by @itsols if you want to keep your design.

Comment: thank you very much Mr: Tom Brunberg  ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Read and Readln statements are common for both, *getting input from the keyboard* AND *reading data from a file*.

About **Readln** from the docs:

> reads one or more values from a file F, and stores the result in V1,
>   V2, etc. **After that it goes to the next line in the file**.

About **Read** from the docs:

> reads one or more values from a file F, and stores the result in V1,
>   V2, etc.

So when reading from a file, readln goes to the next line, while read does not. But this is not the expected behaviour with regards to console input.

If you really want to position the cursor on the screen, I'd advise using the old gotXY command which is also available in FreePascal. [Link to gotoXY](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/crt/gotoxy.html)

eg:

```
write('**  [*] add your Name here: '); 
read(AName); 
gotoXY(28 + length(AName)+ 1, WhereY-1); // Repositionate the cursor to the right Position.
writeln(Complete_Rectangle(length(AName), 70, 28));
```

Comment: Thank you very much iTsols for your answer ....i have updated my question: is there another way to use like the custom read above ..

Comment: I believe you can use readkey but my solution is better. What's the problem with my method? It has worked even in the old Turbo Pascal back in 1990. So it's a proven technique that lives on today for console apps

Comment: sorry Mr: itsols i didn't mean that, I just want to find a quite similar  solution like the custom Read above. or work around the same origin procedure.